# How to get Dropdown to return text value instead of index value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, visual-studio-code

I am currently working on a drop down within my form and it is returning the index value e.g. 0,1,2 when the box is selected. I need it to return the literal text within the box e.g. 'Server One','Server Two' . I am working with the laravel collective forms. attached is the code snippet for the form. Any help would be much appreciated! The variable $statuses is the list of all the servers within the database.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <h1></h1>
    <h1>Edit Incident</h1>

    {!! Form::open(['action' => ['IncidentsController@update', $incident->id], 'method' =>'POST']) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('title','Title')}}
            {{Form::text('title',$incident->title,['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Title'])}}
            {{Form::label('body','Body')}}
            {{Form::textarea('body',$incident->body,['id' => 'article-ckeditor','class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Body text'])}}
            {{Form::label('status','Server Status:')}}
            <br>
            {{Form::label('status','Resolved:')}}
            {{Form::radio('status', 'Resolved' , false) }}
            <br>
            {{Form::label('status','Unresolved:')}}
            {{Form::radio('status', 'Unresolved' , true) }}
            <br>
            {{ Form::label('server', 'Server:') }}
            <br/>
            {{Form::select('server', $statuses),['name' => "server",'class' => 'form-control']}}

        </div>
        {{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}
        {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
    dd($server)
@endsection
```

createIncident:

```
public function createIncident(){
        $statuses = Status::pluck('server');
        dd($statuses);
        return view('createIncident', ['statuses' => $statuses]);
}
```

[result of dd($statuses)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgfmp.png)

Comment: I dont know about laravel, but I am guessing it uses the keys of the array as values for the options? Perhaps using the servers' name as keys of the `$statuses` array might solve it?

Comment: If you want to keep using `Form::` you need to provide `$statuses = ['server one' => 'server one'];`

Comment: @Kyslik would i have to do that then for every single server? The reason for asking is because there will be many servers added over time

Comment: You need to write a code that generates the array.

Comment: $statuses is an array, I will update the question with the code from the method call as well as the result of a die and dump

Comment: You want this for only that selectbox ? also clarify why do you need the literal text rather than value coz in db you are storing numeric ids only so given form is submitted you can always look back the text value of a given id from your db.

Comment: @Viney I do only need it for that select box, I also only need the literally text because in one of my views I have the 'status' as well as 'incidents' objects and I compare if the incident->server === status->server then display some information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up changing the way I displayed and stored the form itself and used select tags to fix it.

```
   <select name="server">
       @foreach($statuses as $key => $value)
           <option>{{$value}}</option>
       @endforeach
   </select>
```

Comment: `<option>` has no value attribute ?

Comment: No need for it, I dont know the exact reasoning why but i would assume its because when I did $key => $value, it automatically stores the $value as the value attribute. strangely enough if i added a value attribute it actually broke it.